# How do I read filenames from a folder and add them into an arraylist without having to make an array and looping all the answers into the arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, directory, filenames

How do I read filenames from a folder and add them into an arraylist without having to make an array and looping all the answers into the arraylist?

For example, lets say I have a list of txt files in a folder. What do I need to do in order for Java to read through each of the file names and add them into a string array list without having to do a `String[]` like other answers have suggested?

Comment: `Files.readAllLines()` is your friend (for reading a single file).

Comment: @GhostCat I think OP wants to read the names of the files in a directory into an `ArrayList`, not the contents.

Comment: Listing the files in a folder is a bit more work, but again, a solved and well documented problem.

Comment: It's unclear. My best guess is to use `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String[]`

Comment: @JacobG. Hmm, maybe. But still, getting file contents ... is also something that many other answers explain.

Comment: No I don't want the file contents, I just want the names into an ArrayList, I couldn't find any threads on this.

Comment: @GhostCat I agree, just wanted to update that duplicate, but it's good now.

Comment: It seems to me that the linked answers do not provide the answer that the asker was looking for, namely a solution that does not involve writing a loop. I'd use: `Files.list(Paths.get("/path/to/folder")).filter(Files::isRegularFile).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: I agree with @akagixxer - the duplicates are all rather ancient and for modern Java, wrong.

Comment: Feel free to put in better answers then!

Comment: @akagixxer You should post that as an answer, since your code does the job the OP is looking for.

Comment: @MCEmperor sure thing. I think I couldn't earlier because the question was locked, marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
File dir = new File(dir);
String[] fileArr  dir.listFiles();
List fileList = Arrays.toList(fileArr); //I bet this is instance of ArrayList

//ArrayList otherFileList = new ArrayList(fileList);
ArrayList otherFileList = new ArrayList();
otherFileList.addAll(fileList);
```

Note: those are the solutions where YOU don,t write the loop but the loop exists in the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or newer you can use the java 'nio' library with java streams to get what you want.

E.g.

```
final List<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get("/path/to/folder"))
  .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```